# Do a mount and its rider share the same space?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, mounted-combat

Does a rider share the same space as its mount?

The rules regarding sharing the same space are clear:

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can't willingly end your move in its space

You'd think riding a creature would be an exception to a rule, but I can't find any mention of that in the mounted combat section.

Comment: Related: [What happens when allies occupy the same space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79814/what-happens-when-allies-occupy-the-same-space)

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes. Because what other space would you be in?

The rules for Mounts state:

> Once during your move, you can mount a creature that is within 5 feet of you or dismount.

The rules say you can mount a creature, and since that naturally involves being in the same space, it is an exception to the rule that says you can’t end your move in the same space as another creature.

Comment: Less an exception and more 'specific beats general'

Comment: You can "grapple" a creature, but the two of you are still in separate adjacent squares. Why wouldn't it be the same for mounting?

Comment: @Guillaume F. Because grappling something doesn't automatically mean you're sitting on that creature. While riding is pretty much a synonym for sitting on a creature. Since you kinda use that creature's legs to move around. And that's pretty much what the rules say. But maybe you tell us, what you're about to do. Why do you wanna use your mount like that?